# Compiler error trying to call converting constructor

Tags: c++

The following code doesn't work. I don't know why. Does that has anything to do with implicit/explicit? Is that called a conversion?

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class A { 
public:

    A(T x) {_x=x;}
    template<typename T2> explicit A(const A<T2> &r) {}
    template<typename T2> explicit A(A<T2> &r){}
    template<typename T2> 
    void operator=(const A<T2>& rhs) { _x = rhs._x; }
    template<typename T2> 
    void operator=(A<T2>& rhs) { _x = rhs._x; }
    T _x; 
};

int main() {
        const A<int> a(10);
        A<int> b = a;
        b = A<int>(5);
        A<int> c(a);
        b(a); // not working. why?
}
```

Error: g++ 6

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:25:12: error: no match for call to ‘(A<int>) (const A<int>&)’
         b(a); // not working. why?
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: compiler error.

Comment: Your copy constructor doesn't take a `const` argument. Also are you expecting to call `b` with `operator()`?

Comment: @tadman which constructor doesn't take `const`?

Comment: `A(T x)` should probably be `A(const T& x)` to follow C++ conventions. You normally take a const reference with your copy constructor.

Comment: @tadman `A(T x) {_x=x;}` is not a copy constructor but your right that passing by reference should be default as `T` could be large and you don't want to make two copies.

Comment: Improve your question title please.

Comment: @NathanOliver The [copy constructor definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) is what I'm talking about here. Is this not a copy constructor by virtue of being a template class? Reading the fine print there implies that.

Comment: @tadman Ah.  Yes, No copy constructor is templated so the user doesn't actually have one and a default one is provided by the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expect `b(a);` to do but it is not going to do what you want.  An object can only be constructed once.  After it has been constructed you cannot reconstruct it.  What you have when you do `b(a);` is you try to call the `operator()` of the class.  Since you do not have one you get a compiler error.  If you want to set `b` to the value of `a` then you need

```
b = a;
```